# Retrieving value in C# from oracle database

Tags: c#

I dont know why but I'm getting an error trying to get the maximum integer value from a table in the oracle database:  Here is the code:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=";
            oradb = oradb + Login.db + ";";
            oradb = oradb + "User Id=" + Login.user;
            oradb = oradb + ";Password=" + Login.pass + ";";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            conn.Open();
            string term = GetTerminal(terminal);
            string sql = "SELECT tallynumber from "+frmSchemas.schema + ".tallies" ;
             MessageBox.Show(sql);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("1");
            Int64 TallyNo = dr.GetInt32(0);  



      // lblTallyNo.Text = (TallyNo).ToString()
```

the returned value should be: 72332 if that is any relevance

Comment: So what does the error message say and on what line does it occurr?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the Following

```
        string sql = "SELECT max(tallynumber) from "+frmSchemas.schema + ".tallies" ;
         MessageBox.Show(sql);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("1");
        if (dr.Read())
        {
        Int64 TallyNo = dr.GetInt32(0); 
        }
```

EDIT:

```
if(dr.Read())
{
Int64 TallyNo = Convert.ToInt64(dr["tallynumber"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: ExecuteScalar is not being recognised by the C#, it underlines it

Comment: int TallyNo = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());

Comment: Ok, You can try with the Code I have given also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the `max value` from a `table`, the `query` should be

```
SELECT max(tallynumber) from ....
```

If you want to get the `max, min etc` values you should be calling `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteReader().`

So you code could become

```
   string sql = "SELECT Max(tallynumber) from "+frmSchemas.schema + ".tallies";              MessageBox.Show(sql);             
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);             
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;             
    object val = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int res = int.MinValue;             
    //MessageBox.Show("1");
  if(int.TryParse(val.ToString(), out res)) 
    Int64 TallyNo = res;
```

Comment: Try it now, changed if(int.TryParse(val, out res))  To if(int.TryParse(val.ToString(), out res))

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `dr.Read();` before accessing the value:

```
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
Int64 TallyNo = dr.GetInt32(0);
```